# Spatstat - how to compare two temperature spatial domains?

Tags: r, spatstat

I would like to compare a satellite pseudo-image generated by the WRF model and a real satellite image with the R-package named Spatstat. However, I do not know how to begin. I have read that it is possible to carry out a spatial pattern comparison but I do not know which function I should use. I have two temperature images in a predefined domain and I would like to know if the comparison is carried out point-by-point over those images or I have to facilitate the model output and satellite data. In that case, how should I do that? Is there any available script?

Thanks in advance. 
Kind regards, Lara.

Comment: Your question appears quite vague and I don't understand what you exactly want to do. Please post some data and plots to help us understand the problem. Do you simply have two n by m matrices of numbers that you are trying to compare value by value?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. We don't have any available data yet. The idea is to compare a simulated satellite image (generated by the WRF model) and a real satellite image. In other words, we would like to compare a model output and a real satellite image to assess the consistency of the model.

Answer (score 0):

The spatstat package is designed mainly to analyse spatial patterns of point locations (like the pattern of locations of accidents that occurred in a given year). It does have some basic facilities for comparing pixel images. If A and B are two pixel images, you can do arithmetic by typing e.g. mean(A-B) or mean(abs(A-B)). There are also some image metrics (distances between images) available. Please visit the spatstat.org website for more information.